# c# find texbox in WinPhone7 silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have something like this:

```
 <ListBox Height="456" Margin="30,113,0,0" x:Name="listBox1" Width="446"  Background="Black">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="28" Padding="10" >
                       <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>  
                            <toolkit:GestureListener 
                                Hold="GestureListenerHold"      />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" FontSize="24" Padding="10" >
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>  
                            <toolkit:GestureListener 
                                Hold="GestureListenerHold"      />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}" FontSize="24" Padding="10">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>  
                            <toolkit:GestureListener 
                                Hold="GestureListenerHold"      />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>


            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and in my app i do:

```
   data = (List<Device>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                       this.listBox1.ItemsSource = data;
```

on every textblock I have a gesture listener which should provide the user with the option to change 'name', so when they hold the textblock the app navigates him to another page where he fills in the form.

My question is how to find the texblock which is binding 'name' when I click and hold another texblock?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq-to-VisualTree, a utility which I wrote which allows you to navigate the visual tree:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/

Firstly, name the `TextBlock` so that it can be uniquely identified:

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="NameText" Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="28" Padding="10" />
```

Then, when one of your other TextBlocks is tapped, you can find it as follows:

```
// locate the parent stackpanel
var parentStackPanel = tappedTextBlock.Ancestors().First()

// locate the names TextBlock
var nameTextBlock = parentStackPanel.Elements()
                                    .Where(el => el.Name == "NameText").Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `sender` in the `GestureListenerHold` method.